# Can you play FIFA 15 Co-op on one team with 3 players?

Tags: ps3, fifa-15

I was wondering if you can play with 3 players Co-op on one team, or 2 v 1 ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. Simply go into a game, have three controllers on, and decide which players are going to be on which team when it displays the screen to decide which controller plays which side. Have a 2-on-1 game or have all three on the same team. The same can be done with four players, as well.